# C++ Grid gravity simulation opzimization (Kattis Falling Apples)

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, simulation

I have a solution for the Kattis Falling Apples problem ([link](https://open.kattis.com/problems/apples)).  The input is a grid of *R* rows (up to 50000) by *C* columns (up to 10).  At each timestep, apples (indicated by `'a'`) move down one cell into an empty space (denoted by `.`) or rest upon an obstacle (marked by `#`).

My solution exceeds time limit only at the last test case.  I'm thinking the while loop is the problem, but I have no idea what I could do to optimize it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r; // Grid rows
    int c; // Grid columns

    scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);

    char grid[r][c];

    // Establish grid
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        char line[c];
        scanf("%s", &line);
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = line[j];
        }
    }

    // Loop to change
    while (true) {
        bool change = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {

                if (grid[i][j] == 'a' && grid[i + 1][j] == '.') {
                    grid[i + 1][j] = 'a';
                    grid[i][j] = '.';
                    change = true;
                }

            }
        }

        if (!change) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Print the grid
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            cout << grid[i][j];
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your post has been edited to correct indenation- see [code formatting](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help#link-code) for more information on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

- Avoid allocating large arrays on a stack. According to the restrictions, `grid` may take up to half a meg. You are dangerously close to stack overflow.
- Avoid single letter identifiers. Spelling out `row` and `col` wouldn't make your program any slower, but it would make it much more readable.
- `scanf` adds a null terminator to a string. Your `char line[c]` is one character short. Definite UB.
- The problem statement clearly says that

  > Merely iterating the gravity rule, a step at a time, will likely take too long on large datasets.

  but that is exactly what your code is doing. No optimization may salvage this algorithm. You need to rethink the approach.

  I don't want to spell out a solution, but here are few hints:

  1. Columns are totally independent. Do one column at a time.
  2. Do not drop apples. Count them.
  3. It is beneficial to add an artificial row of obstacles at the bottom.